# Get Exception Details in Application Insights webhook JSON

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I've configured an Application Insights alert to be triggered on Server Exceptions.
I'm handling this alert through a logic app, which is working fine.

I want to edit the alert payload JSON so that it contains the exception details in it.
From the available [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-webhooks-alerts) on setting up alerts, it seems that we can edit properties to include some custom data, which can be set using Azure Monitor APIs

Azure Monitor API [Alert Rules Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertrules) doesn't mention much about this.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the details error message from the exception and send these message to the AI? As far as I know, the output will get the error message, you could use logic app call azure function, in the azure function send these error message to the AI. About how to call the azure function in logic app, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-scenario-function-sb-trigger).

Comment: @BrandoZhang, yes I was able to get this working through a logic app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exception information sent to Application Insights try these classes out.

```
public static class StaticLogger
{
    private static Object theThreadLock = new Object();

    private static TelemetryClient _APM;
    public static TelemetryClient APM
    {
        get
        {
            lock (theThreadLock)
            {
                if (_APM == null) { _APM = new TelemetryClient(); }
                return _APM;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Warning(string message)
    {            
        APM.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Warning);
    }                

    public static void Error(Exception exception,LoggerEvents logEvent)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            var telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(exception);
            APM.TrackEvent(logEvent.ToString());

            APM.TrackException(telemetry);
        }
    }

    public static void Error(Exception exception,LoggerEvents logEvent, string fmt, params object[] vars)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            var telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(exception);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("message", string.Format(fmt, vars));

            APM.TrackException(telemetry);
        }
    }

    public static void Trace(string Message, string userID)
    {
        lock(theThreadLock)
        {
            APM.Context.User.Id = userID.ToString();
            Trace(Message);
        }

    }
    public static void Trace(string Message)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            APM.TrackTrace(Message);
        }
    }

    public static void TraceAPI(string currentNameSpace,string componentName, string method, string httpAction, TimeSpan timespan)
    {
        TraceAPI(currentNameSpace,componentName, method, httpAction, timespan, string.Empty);
    }

    public static void TraceAPI(string currentNameSpace,string componentName, string method, string httpAction, TimeSpan timespan, string fmt, params object[] vars)
    {
        TraceAPI(currentNameSpace,componentName, method, httpAction, timespan, string.Format(fmt, vars));
    }

    public static void TraceAPI(string currentNameSpace,string componentName, string method, string httpAction, TimeSpan timespan, string properties)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            var telemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Trace API call", SeverityLevel.Information);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("namespace", currentNameSpace);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("component", componentName);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("method", method);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("HttpAction", httpAction);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("timespan", timespan.ToString());

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(properties))
                telemetry.Properties.Add("properties", properties);

            APM.TrackTrace(telemetry);
        }
    }

    public static void TraceAPI(string currentNameSpace, string componentName, string method, string httpAction, TimeSpan timespan, IDictionary<string, string> properties = null)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            var telemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Trace API call", SeverityLevel.Information);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("namespace", currentNameSpace);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("component", componentName);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("method", method);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("HttpAction", httpAction);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("timespan", timespan.ToString());

            if (properties != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    telemetry.Properties.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
                }
            }

            APM.TrackTrace(telemetry);
        }
    }

    public static void TraceMethod(string currentNameSpace, string componentName, string method, TimeSpan timespan, string properties)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            var telemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Trace API call", SeverityLevel.Information);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("namespace", currentNameSpace);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("component", componentName);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("method", method);                
            telemetry.Properties.Add("timespan", timespan.ToString());

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(properties))
                telemetry.Properties.Add("properties", properties);

            APM.TrackTrace(telemetry);
        }
    }

    public static void TraceMethod(string currentNameSpace, string componentName, string method, TimeSpan timespan, IDictionary<string, string> properties = null)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            var telemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Trace API call", SeverityLevel.Information);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("namespace", currentNameSpace);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("component", componentName);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("method", method);
            telemetry.Properties.Add("timespan", timespan.ToString());

            if (properties != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    telemetry.Properties.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
                }
            }

            APM.TrackTrace(telemetry);
        }
    }
    public static void TrackEvent(string message)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            APM.TrackEvent(message);
        }
    }

    public static void TrackEvent(string message, IDictionary<string, string> properties)
    {
        lock (theThreadLock)
        {
            var telemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Track Event", SeverityLevel.Information);
            telemetry.Message = message;

            if (properties != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    telemetry.Properties.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
                }
            }

            APM.TrackEvent(message);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class LoggerEvents
{
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly int value;

    public readonly static LoggerEvents ErrorWebSite = new LoggerEvents(1, "Error:WebSite");
    public readonly static LoggerEvents UnhandledException = new LoggerEvents(2, "UnhandledException");
    public readonly static LoggerEvents UserNotActive = new LoggerEvents(3, "UserNotActive");
    public readonly static LoggerEvents InvalidURL = new LoggerEvents(4, "InvalidURL");
    public readonly static LoggerEvents ConsentRefused = new LoggerEvents(5,"ConsentRefused");
    public readonly static LoggerEvents ConsentAccepted = new LoggerEvents(6, "ConsentAccepted");
    public readonly static LoggerEvents UserLoginSuccess = new LoggerEvents(7, "LoginSuccess");
    public readonly static LoggerEvents UserLoginFailure = new LoggerEvents(7, "LoginFailure");
    private LoggerEvents(int value, string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: No my concern is not sending exception information to ApplicationInsights. I've already done that.

Comment: The sample class has the examples on how to send extra data, properties and the use of Exception Telemetry.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the exception details using an Analytics Query in the Logic App.
I ran a query, which fetched all exceptions in the last 5 minutes.
Then I passed this using the HTTP action to my API for further handling.